# Convert character to code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding

I have the following string:

```
string = "Good « Bad"
```

The `«` has a code of `X00AB`. How can I convert `string` to `"Good \X00AB Bad"`?

I am doing this to search for `\X00AB`, then replace it to the nearest symbol, which is `"`. I don't want to search `«` because it's inaccurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert it at all. Unicode characters in Ruby can be used like this:

```
c = "\u00AB"
```

(notice that it's \u, not \X)

"\u00AB" and "«" are actually the same character:

```
"\u00AB" == "«"
=> true
```

So you can search as you wanted:

```
string = "Good « Bad"
string.include?("\u00AB")
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace non-ASCII codepoints with their UTF code representations by using [Array#pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-pack):

```
string.gsub(/[^[:ascii:]]/) do |char|
  char.codepoints.pack("s>")
end # => "Good \x00\xAB Bad"
```

But maybe it's better not to hardcode those conversions by hand, and use a standard tool for those conversions, [iconv](https://rubygems.org/gems/iconv)?

```
require 'iconv'
Iconv.conv('ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'UTF8', string) # => "Good << Bad"
```